# deploy application with oracle+entity framework

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, installation

I'm trying to deploy(install) application on client machine. And I'm getting this error Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

Any help?

Comment: need a lot more information for this... what provider have you defined in your web.config, is provider actually installed on client?  Just sounds like whatever provider you have defined to use, isn't actually on your client machine

Comment: <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModelInventoryXXX.csdl|res://*/ModelInventoryXXX.ssdl|res://*/ModelInventoryDBCHEM.msl;provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=EUSHEET;PASSWORD=dbchem123;USER ID=MILOS&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> this is coonection string

Comment: and you are sure that those providers are installed on the client machine?

Comment: Yes to be even strangerger  I can execute oraclecommand from .net

Comment: Did you install the data provider as an administrator with at least local admin privileges?

Comment: No, that's not a problem, I cannot understand why only entity framework cannot "see" ODP provider, normal OracleConnection is functioning OK. Is there any other solution for deploying applciation that uses entity framework with oracle?

Comment: I recently had a similar issue and the problem was that the ODP registry values had not been added to the Windows registry tree. Maybe take a look at [link]http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e18754/featConfig.htm#ODPNT157 under the "Windows Registry" heading